# Unable to call a custom dll method in Microsoft SSRS

Tags: .net, reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

as soon as I try to call a function from a simple custom DLL in SSRS, I receive an error message that requires me to load .NET DLLs such as system.runtime.dll and system.private.corelib.dll .

I encounter this error message for any custom dll.

I have followed various tutorials and the official documentation, but the problem persists.

Thank you.

Comment: Hello, My project targets .NET version 6 (netcore ) and my system works on net.standard 4.8. Apologies for the lack of precision regarding the error message; I don't have access to the PC until Monday. However, SSRS simply states when I declare my function in an expression from my DLL that it is imperative to load the 'system.runtime 6.0.0' DLL. Initially, I tried loading this .NET DLL directly into SSRS, but then it asks for 'system.private.corelib.dll,' which I find strange.

Comment: I also add that the version of ssrs is that of 2019, the error message also appears with the 2022 version